# Delta PLC connection with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
Im working on project where i need to connect PLC's to ROS.
I sucessfully connected Siemens PLC s7-1200 through MODBUS, but now i need to connect DELTA AS228P.
I've searched internet for answers but find nothing.

Any piece of information will be worth a lot.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392558/delta-plc-connection-with-ros/) by [dhiman](https://answers.ros.org/users/87716/dhiman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @dhiman,

I am not sure whether my solution will be correct for you, but I am giving an overview of how you can connect Delta PLC with ROS.

Let's say you are using python [pyModbusTCP](https://pypi.org/project/pyModbusTCP/) to connect your code with your DELTA AS228P or in CPP, and you can use [libmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus).

Code example of Python side.

```
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
c=ModbusClient(host='localhost',port=9999,auto_ope n=True)

regs=c.read_holding_registers(403705,1)
print("reading register values")

if regs:
  print(regs)
else:
  print("error")

print("write value to register")
a=int(input())
c.write_single_register(403705,a)
```

Let's say your python or CPP code is working correctly, and you can communicate to your IO via ethernet. Now you can directly create hardware packages based on the above code. The hardware packages with [nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes), [topics](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics), and [services](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams) can be used  based on your application requirement.

I hope that will help you. Feel free to drop a comment in case of any query.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The as200 series has an modbus client and server so you can use the same solution as with the Siemens you already done.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1